# How to set environmental variable in Qunit

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

I am stuck to test the function that use $j(window).width(). This function return value according to this.Now my problem is this that i want to set window width in my Qunit function.Can any body help ???

Comment: Does `$j(window).width(setValue)` not work?

Comment: $j(window).width(setValue) = 600 like this ??? actully i have no idea about this

Comment: Try `$j(window).width(600)`

Comment: What do you mean it's not working?  Do you get an error?  Does anything happen?  What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I use this $j(window).width(600) in my qunit test case. Now i expect that the javascript function that is call by this test case width = $j(window).width() . Now i suppose that width will be 600 but it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In situations when you are expecting a value returned from an object that you don't control or at least need to test, you should mock the return values. Take a look at [JSMockito](http://jsmockito.org/) which is a JavaScript based mocking framework. Below is a simple example that mocks an Array object and sets the value to be returned when the test calls `get(1)` method.

```
var mockedObject = mock(Array);

when(mockedObject).get(1).thenReturn("hello world");

// -- start code under test --
alert(mockedObject.get(1));

// the following alerts 'true' as get(99) was not stubbed
alert(typeof (mockedObject.get(99)) === 'undefined');
// -- end code under test --
```

Hope this helps!